# Relative Paths not Working with routerLink in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router

I'm having a bit of an issue with Angular app I'm building. I've noticed that application-wide, using relative paths with routerLink doesn't work. It doesn't throw an error, or navigate to the wrong page, it simply does nothing; I've tested this trying to navigate to root-level components, as well as children with the same result. If, however I use absolute paths, it routes just fine.

I'm really scratching my head on this one, and I can't find a similar problem on SO etc, so I just need to know to where to begin looking.

**Edit**: It works it will append one time when the app first loads, if it's the first link you hit, but never again.

**Update**: As suggested, I have recreated the issue in StackBlitz. PLease follow this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drchnd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnav-component%2Fnav-component.component.html) and read the comments in `nav-component.component.html`.

For instance, the first link in this menu does nothing whatsoever, but all the others work as expected; and again, I've tested this on every link in the app with the same results:

```
<div class="list-group menu-list-group">

  <a routerLink="./artists-profiles"
     class="list-group-item btn btn-primary"
  (click)="artistsMenuChoice('artist-profiles')">
    Artist Profiles
  </a>

  <a [routerLink]="['/artists/artist-videos']"
     class="list-group-item btn btn-primary">
    Videos
  </a>

  <a [routerLink]="['/artists/artist-endorsement']"
     class="list-group-item btn btn-primary">
    Get Endorsed
  </a>

</div>

<hr>

<div class="list-group menu-list-group">

  <a href="#" class="list-group-item btn btn-primary">
    Shopping Cart
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="list-group-item btn btn-primary">
    {{ menuCredAction }}
  </a>

</div>
```

Here is my app-routing module:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'artists', component: ArtistsComponent, children: [
      {path: '', component: ArtistsStartComponent},
      {path: 'artist-profiles', component: ArtistProfilesComponent},
      {path: 'artist-videos', component: ArtistVideosComponent},
      {path: 'artist-endorsement', component: ArtistsGetEndorsedComponent},
    ] },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent, children: [
      {path: '', component: AboutStartComponent}
    ] },
  { path: 'shop', component: ShopComponent },
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
  { path: 'auth', component: AuthComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],

})
export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first link be: `routerLink="/artists"`

Comment: No, it should actually be `./artist-profiles` and I just changed it back. That was there because I was playing with it to see if would append to the current path.

Comment: Strange! Would it be possible for you to create a simple [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) replicating this issue?

Comment: If I had ever used stackblitz, sure. But I really don't have time to learn some new platform for at least a while.

Comment: If the current activated route is `artists` (you are in _ArtistsComponent_) and you set `[routerLink]="[./artists-profiles]"` it should work. If it doesn't, I suggest injecting `ActivatedRoute` in constructor and logging current route. Also, you can inject `Router` and check all routes, it may help you fix the issue.

Comment: Would you please try it out once? It's an Online IDE with an interface just like Visual Studio Code which you might be using right now I guess.

Comment: @SiddAjmera - I have created a StackBlitz and the link is in the "update" section of my post.

Answer (score 2):

> The routing is done based on the the router config 'tree' which does not necessarily match what the URL path is.

Based on where the html you provided is placed, the relative path can be different even if the url is the same. Easy way to debug this is to log the `ActivatedRoute.url` or `ActivatedRoute.routeConfig` in the component where the link lives.

[Link to quote in github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13011#issuecomment-364815580)

Comment: That particular link is not even visible unless you are at `/artist/` so appending to that should produce `/artist/artist-profiles/`

Comment: I've also tested it on the root level, with the same effect.

Comment: I was hoping your suggestion to log `ActivatedRoute.url` might give some enlightening info, but it logs the url exactly as one would expect when navigating to the parent route. In a bizarre twist, the url it shows for a child route only shows the child's section of the route, not appended to the url of the parent route.

Comment: I need more code in order to help, can you replicate you problem [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-crwcd9)?

Comment: I have recreated the issue in StackBlitz. Please have a look at the "update" section of the original post.